# GA Updated to UA however old tracking code is in use

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have a website which has their Google Analytics updated to the Universal Analytics (from the Upgrade Center) however all this while they have been using the Classical Analytics tracking code on the site till date. So that means the implementation is old however, the Analytics end is upgraded to the latest version.

I needed the SO community to comment on the below questions if the tracking code is updated to UA (via GTM - PageView tag)

- Will there be any impacts in terms of the way Google collects data?
- Will the bounce rate change, avg. session time change?

Answer (score 0):

when you update a GA account to Universal Analytics the tracking code stays the same, you don't need to change it.

If you change the UA don't forget that the data in your old one will not be displayed together.

If you do not change the UA the basic data will still be collected the same way, so your pageviews average number, the bounce rate and session time should stay the same. 
What changes is that using Universal Analytics you will have custom dimension and custom metrics instead of custom vars, Enhanced Ecommerce and more complex data. You can see more here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en

Comment: I agree with Vitor, you do not *need* to change the code but you really *should* upgrade the code to universal analytics.  There are many features you cannot access using the classic code and the ga.js is heavier and not maintained significantly anymore.

Comment: Apologies if I am using the wrong terminologies here, but by changing the tracking code I mean the below snippet: `(function(){var ga=document.createElement('script');ga.type='text/javascript';ga.async=true;ga.src=('https:'==document.location.protocol?'https://ssl':'http://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);})();var _gaq=_gaq||[];_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-1234567-1']);_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The above snippet in my prev. comment is still being used (I am guessing this is Classical Analytics tracking code) and I want this to be updated to the Universal Analytics tracking code (might fire it using GTM). So my question, upgrading the way the pageview tag/event tracking tag/etc. being fried from Classical Analytics to Universal Analytics would have no impact whatsoever?

Comment: Hiren, the same code will still work for the Universal Analytics, so you will not lost pageviews, and then you migth change the code to the new one.